# Recursive form of the Kravchuk polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recursion

I recently read an [article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tech.2009.07120) where they used the Kravchuk polynomials:

$$P_{j}(x ; n)=\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
i
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-x \\
j-i
\end{array}\right)\text{,}$$
which are [discrete orthogonal polynomials associated with the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kravchuk_polynomials). However, they mention that the polynomials can be easily calculated using the following recursive formula:

- $P_{0}(x ; n)=1$
- $P_{j}(0 ; n)= \left(\begin{array}{l}
  n \\
  j
  \end{array}\right)$
- $P_{j}(x ; n)=P_{j}(x-1 ; n) - P_{j-1}(x ; n) -P_{j-1}(x-1 ; n)$

I cannot figure out how they obtained this recursive formula, and the article provides no reference so I'm asking for help.

Also, they compute this polynomial for values of $j$ and $x$ both ranging from $0$ to $n$. And I'm wondering what happens to the binomial coefficient $\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
i
\end{array}\right)$, when $j>x$ and that some values of $i$ are also larger than $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $k>n$, the usual convention is that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ -- which matches the combinatorial viewpoint that there is no way to choose $k$ elements in a set of $n$ elements.

As for the recurrence formula, it can be deduced from successive applications of Pascal's identity:

$$\begin{align*}
P_j(x,n)+P_{j-1}(x,n)&=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i \left(\binom{x}{i} \binom{n-x}{j-i}+\binom{x}{i} \binom{n-x}{j-i-1}\right)+(-1)^j\binom{x}{j}\\
        &=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i \binom{x}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}+(-1)^j\binom{x}{j}\\
        &=\sum_{i=0}^{j} (-1)^i \binom{x}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}\\
        &=\sum_{i=0}^{j} (-1)^i \binom{x-1}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}+\sum_{i=1}^{j} (-1)^i\binom{x-1}{i-1} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}\\
        &=\sum_{i=0}^{j} (-1)^i \binom{x-1}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i\binom{x-1}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i-1}\\
        &= P_j(x-1,n)-P_{j-1}(x-1,n).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Very nice work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I don't see how you make the change between the last 3 lines, i.e. how does $\sum_{i=1}^{j} (-1)^i\binom{x-1}{i-1} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i}$ becomes $ - \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i\binom{x-1}{i} \binom{n-x+1}{j-i-1}$ ? Is it also through pascal's formula where $ \binom{x-1}{i-1} = \binom{x}{i} - \binom{x-1}{i}$ ?

Comment: @A.Bohyn - it's just a change of variable in the sum (I replace $i-1$ by $i$ and I sum from $0$ to $j-1$ instead of $1$ to $j$)